# Method identifier expected внутри оператора with

Tags: delphi

Код очень большой, скажите что именно показать, покажу. Внезапно выбило ошибку в казалось совсем безобидном операторе with:

```
with TMainForm.strngrdRoute do
  begin
  ...
  end;
```

Ошибку показывает сразу после TMainForm. в чем проблема даже не могу представить. 
При этом сам метод где написаны эти строчки является просто внешним методом. StrngrdRoute принадлежит форме, здесь все правильно. Какой метод он там ждет я ума не приложу.
ЗЫ Сама ошибка, на всякий: "[dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(404): E2096 Method identifier expected"

Answer (score 1):

Такой код может быть правильным только если метод `strngrdRoute` у вас ["статический метод класса"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Methods#Class_Static_Methods) и возвращает какой-то объект. Подозреваю, что метод у вас обычный, поэтому скорее всего:

```
with MainForm.strngrdRoute do 
begin 
  ... 
end;
```

впрочем, дальше возможны варианты других ошибок...

Comment: `strngrdRoute` - это визуальный компонент `TStringGrid`.